# Connected manifold with disconnected boundary?

Tags: manifolds

Is there any simple example of a connected manifold with disconnected boundary?

Comment: Perhaps an open-ended cylinder?

Comment: Or just $[0..1]$. (I don’t get that cylinder-example, though @ThomasAndrews.)

Comment: It's just $S^1\times [0,1]$, @k.stm

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ah. How is this “open-ended”?

Comment: The boundary of the solid cylinder is a closed can with ends - topologically, it is a sphere. By "open-ended," I just meant there are no caps. Don't think it is a technical term. @k.stm

Comment: Because the boundary isn't included in the cylinder... it would be better to say $S^1 \times ]0,1[,$ no?

Comment: No, that is not what I meant, @IvoTerek.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Because this is what “open-ended cylinder” sounds like to me, a “$S^1 × (0..1)$”.

Comment: You guys read too much math, not enough common language. Google "open-ended cylinder" and all the early usages are describing uncapped cylinders. Basically, toilet paper rolls. @k.stm

Comment: Some of those usages, however, seem to be using it to indicate a single cap is missing, and use the term "double open-ended cylinder" for the toilet paper roll.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only are there many connected manifolds with disconnected boundaries (such as $[0,1]$ or a cylinder), there is an equivalence relation built on it called [cobordism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cobordism), where two manifolds are said to be cobordant if their disjoint union is the boundary of a manifold one dimension higher. Technically, the higher dimensional manifold need not be connected, but this is often the case.